# Phaser JS - Holding click on button, moving mouse away, and letting go of click triggers onMouseUp

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm taking up Phaser, and practicing with the basic button.

For an example, look no further than the Phaser button example [right here](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/buttons/action-on-click).

However, I noticed that if you hold down your mouse click on the Phaser button, move the mouse away from the button, and let go of your mouse click, the Phaser button still activates as if the mouse was right on top of it.

You can also try holding the mouse click on the Phaser button, and then moving your mouse out of the frame. The Phaser button will also activate.

I'm not sure if this is the default behaviour for buttons in Phaser, but it's not for other JS game libraries / engines like Cocos 2D JS.

So far, I've tried the following:

- Setting the button to activate `onInputDown` - not really preferred.
- Setting another function `onInputUp` - doesn't change the behaviour.

Here's my code:

```
this.playButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX - 100, this.game.world.centerY + 230, 'ui', this.actionOnClick, this, 'ui_btn_play_U.png', 'ui_btn_play_U.png', 'ui_btn_play_D.png', 'ui_btn_play_U.png');
this.playButton.onInputUp.add(this.startGameplay, this);

actionOnClick() {

}

startGameplay() {

    this.clickButton();
    this.bgm.stop();
    var slideOut = Phaser.Plugin.StateTransition.Out.SlideTop;
    slideOut.duration = 1000;

    var slideIn = Phaser.Plugin.StateTransition.In.SlideTop;
    slideIn.duration = 1000;

    this.game.state.start('gameplay' , slideOut );

}
```

What can I do to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue time ago and that's how I solved it:
You need to combine three events onInputDown, onInputUp and onInputOut. In pseudo-code it would be like the following:

```
myButton.clicked=false;
When myButton.onInputDown -> myButton.clicked=true
When myButton.onInputOut -> myButton.clicked= false
When myButton.onInputUp -> if (myButton.clicked) then do desired action
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I did it too, a few days later. I was hoping there was a built-in solution, or at least one that didn't require me to essentially right two extra functions. But thanks just the same.